# For Loop initializing

Tags: c++

I have a simple question. I am doing an assignment but i have not studied for loop much so i have a question about it

```
c1=6;
for (i=0; i<7 ; i++)
    {
    for (x=0, x<c1 ,x++)
        {
        cout<<"*";
        }
    x=0;
    c1--;
    }


c1=6;
    for (i=0; i<7 ; i++)
        {
        for (x=0, x<c1 ,x++)
            {
            cout<<"*";
            }
        c1--;
        }
```

These both are different codes one have x=0 other doesnt..
Does for loop automatically initializes x value to 0 before starting every time?
I need this x=0 in for loop Yes or no? (P.s i have studied while loop alot we need it in while loop)

Comment: If you don't have `x=0` in your for loop nobody is going to magically set it for you.

Comment: Does this code compile?

Comment: @EdHeal I'm guessing the **s are for emphasis rather than part of the code.

Comment: `;` not `,`! You've been misreading something.

Comment: you should post your entire code and explain what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I was thinking the lack of ; in the for statements

Comment: How are the variables declared?  And what are these '**'?  I also think that you don't have to "study" loops.  It is sufficient to read about them.  Loops are not rocket science

Comment: Thank you guys,though my question is still unanswered is it Yes or no.. ? Just edited ** i was trying to make it bold (Sorry new here not familiar enough)

Answer (score 3):

Lets take a simple `for` loop, like the one you have:

```
for (i=0; i<7; i++)
{
    // statements...
}
```

It's equivalent to the following code:

```
{
    i=0;
    while (i<7)
    {
        // statements...
        i++;
    }
}
```

This is for *all* `for` loops.

So to answer your question: The initialization is done before the `for` loop *always*.

Comment: Should those commas be semi-colons?

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need to reinitialize x = 0 in your code. That's what the x=0 in your for loop is for. The for loop automatically initializes x to the value you set when starting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do need the x in your for loop. x is initialized inside your for loop. A for loop statement is composed of 3 parts, Variable initialization; your condition; and updating your variable. You will get an error with out it.

```
for (var initialization; condition; var update)
{
    //code..... 
}
```

the difference between a while loop and a for loop is a while loop you initialize your variable before your while loop and update your variable within the loop it self.

```
x = 0
while (x < 5)
{
    x++
}
```

A for loop, it is all contained within the for statement.

```
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
    //code...
}
```

So in your second for loop statement x is already being initialized to 0 within the for statement.

Also your for loop with the x's should have ; not ,

Answer (score 0):

statements are put after you initialize before the for loop. They are put inside the body of the for loop.